# Fiddler to capture external webserver in PHP curl

Tags: php, curl, fiddler

I need to capture the request headers and response while using PHP cURL to post data to external API call. The localhost page load shows in traffic where as the PHP cURL is not shown.

```
$url = "https://https://gds.eligibleapi.com/v1.3/enrollment.json";

$ch = curl_init(); // initialize curl handle   
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // set url to post to
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); // Fail on errors
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // allow redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); // return into a variable 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string); // add POST fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)));


curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);


$data = curl_exec($ch); // if($data === false) echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);

echo     $data;

$http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your URL is malformed (you have `https://https://`).

You need to set the Proxy option on the CURL command, e.g.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8888');
```

See http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigurePHPcURL

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the url issue. Fiddler still didnt show the external domain traffic. I followed the steps mentioned in the document too.. Is fiddler expected to show traffic to same domain only if proxy is used?

Comment: Fiddler cannot "magically" see traffic sent from one remote computer to another remote computer. If cURL is running on a remote computer, you either need to have Fiddler running on that remote computer, or you need to configure cURL to use the Fiddler-running computer as a proxy (and "Allow remote computers to connect" inside Fiddler).

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure Fiddler to decrypt HTTPS traffic.

See here http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/DecryptHTTPS

Comment: Thats on..but the GET request for the php page is shown,but not the cURL request to the external domain.